# Wordpress front-end post form and email after

Tags: front-end, email

I have coded a front-end form that posts to a custom post type, i have a form input field for an email and when the form posts to the custom post type i want an email sent to the email address inserted into the email input when it's submitted.

Any ideas??

Edit...Here's my code (forgot lol)

```
if('POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) &&  $_POST['action'] == "new_booking") {

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $sucess = "We will contact you regarding this booking.";

    $errors = "";

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_name'])) {
        $booking_name = trim($_POST['booking_name']);
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter your name.</li>";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_email'])) {
        $booking_email = trim($_POST['booking_email']);
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter your email.</li>";  
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_address'])) {
        $booking_address = trim($_POST['booking_address']);
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter your address.</li>";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_phone'])) {
        $booking_phone = trim($_POST['booking_phone']);
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter your phone number.</li>";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_rooms'])) {
        $booking_rooms = trim($_POST['booking_rooms']);
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter number of rooms.</li>";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_adults'])) {
        $booking_adults = $_POST['booking_adults'];
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter number of adults.</li>";
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_arrival'])) {
        $booking_arrival = trim($_POST['booking_arrival']);
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter an arrival date.</li>";  
    }

    if(!empty($_POST['booking_departure'])) {
        $booking_departure = trim($_POST['booking_departure']);
    } else {
        $errors .= "<li>Please enter a departure date.</li>";  
    }

    $booking_requirements = trim($_POST['booking_requirements']);

    if(empty($errors)) {
        $new_booking = array(
            'post_title' => $booking_name,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_type' => 'listings',
            'booking_email' => $booking_email,
            'booking_address' => $booking_address,
            'booking_phone' => $booking_phone,
            'booking_rooms' => $booking_rooms,
            'booking_adults' => $booking_adults,
            'booking_arrival' => $booking_arrival,
            'booking_departure' => $booking_departure,
            'booking_requirements' => $booking_requirements
        );

        $pid = wp_insert_post($new_booking);

        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_email', $booking_email, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_address', $booking_address, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_phone', $booking_phone, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_rooms', $booking_rooms, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_adults', $booking_adults, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_arrival', $booking_arrival, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_departure', $booking_departure, true);
        add_post_meta($pid, 'booking_requirements', $booking_requirements, true);

    }

}
```

}

do_action('wp_insert_post', 'wp_insert_post');

Comment: You should post your code so folks can assist you.

Comment: code has been added :)

Answer (score 0):

Put this after your if empty $errors and edit to meet your needs:

```
if(empty($errors)) {
$subject = __('[Your Subject]', 'your_text_domain').' '.$title;
$body = __("Name: ","your_text_domain").$booking_name;
$body .= __("\n\nEmail: ","your_text_domain").$booking_email;
$body .= __("\n\nPhone: ","your_text_domain").$booking_phone;
$body .= __("\n\nMessage: ","your_text_domain").$message;

$headers = __('From: your@email.com ', 'your_text_domain').' <'.$booking_email.'>' . "\r\n" . __('Reply-To: ','your_text_domain') . $email; // Change this $email to whatever you want where you will get messages from booked persons

$mail_sent = false;
$mail_sent = mail($mailto, $subject, $body, $headers);

if ($mail_sent == true) {
    echo __('Your message has been sent succesfully.','your_text_domain');      
} else {
    $error = true;
    echo __('Sorry, an error occured while sending your message. Please try again.','your_text_domain');        
    }
}
```